# Active record query with foreign key

Tags: sql, activerecord, foreign-keys, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a Category model :

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :products
end
```

with this db schema:

```
create_table "categories", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
```

and a Product model :

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :category
end
```

with this db schema:

```
create_table "products", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "origin"
    t.string "name"
    t.text "description"
    t.bigint "category_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["category_id"], name: "index_products_on_category_id"
  end
```

In my seed I have only 2 categories ('coffee' and 'equipment') and some products have been seeded with categorie: coffee. 
I am trying to make a simple active record query in my home controller to select only the products that have the category name of coffee. 
I tried:

```
@coffees = Product.joins(:category).where("name = 'coffee'")
```

and

```
@coffees = Product.joins(:category).where("category.name = 'coffee'")
```

and

```
@coffees = Product.where("product.category.name == 'coffee' ")
```

But none of them is working, I can't display the array on my home view. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used wrong table name. There is no table named 'category'.

I think it should be like this instead :

```
@coffees = Product.joins(:category).where("categories.name = 'coffee'")
```